# Validar que textBox1 no puede tener un valor menos a 0

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una interfaz donde un boton incrementa el valor y otro boton decrementa el valor de un textbox, y colo que la condicion que cuando sea mayor a 24 le diga que no puede ser mayor a 24 y otra condicion donde no puede ser menor a 0, pero igual ocurre este es mi codigo

```
int count = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        if (count < maxMinute)
        {
            count--;
            textBox2.Text = count.ToString();
        }
        if(count<0)
        {
            this.TextMessage = "Los minutos no pueden ser menor a 0.";
            this.ShowMessageForm();
            count = minMinute;
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aun que si manda el messageBox sigue decrementando intente declarando una variable

```
private int maxMinute;
        private int minMinute;
        private int maxHour;
        private int minHour;
        private int Minute;
        private BizKitchenNEWConfiguration obj = new BizKitchenNEWConfiguration();
        public DepuracionInfo()
        {
            this.messageForm = new MessageForm();
            this.TextMessage = String.Empty;
            this.maxMinute = 60;
            this.minMinute = 0;
            this.maxHour = 24;
            this.minHour = 0;
            this.Minute = 0;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Pero no hace lo que le dijo que es de que si es mayor a 24 o menor a 0

```
count = minMinute;
```

Comment: Si eso es lo que tengo, count = textBox2.Text, pero no funciona adecuadamente solo manda el messageBox

Comment: Me refiero al reves. Despues de hacer `count = minMinute;` intenta añadir `textBox2.Text = count`. El problema es que pones count a 0 cuando es menor que 0, pero en el textbox ya tienes -1, que en la siguente vez que llamas se mete en `count`

Answer (score 0):

```
        int count = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

        if (count < maxMinute)
        {
            count--;
            textBox2.Text = count.ToString();
        }
        if(count<0)
        {
            this.TextMessage = "Los minutos no pueden ser menor a 0.";
            this.ShowMessageForm();
            count = minMinute;
            textBox2.Text = count;
        }
```